# Assigning multiple subjects to a student

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am facing a problem while assigning multiple subjects to a student. A student studying in 10th standard can study biology or computer with rest of compulsory subjects. Now i want to connect two tables 'students' and 'subjects' in a manner that if a student studies biology or computer than a list of all subjects will be associated with his/her id containing biology or computer. Following are the tables: 
Student Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `student_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `student_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `father_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `subject_group` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Subject Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
  `subject_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `subject_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: add student id also in subjects table.

Comment: Create a new many-to-many mapping table `student_to_subject`. It will have two fields student_id and subject_id

Comment: @PHPGeek I have added student id in subject table. Now can you please guide how to apply foreign key so that all subjects with biology or computer will be assigned to student id

Comment: this is not good. Subject table should only have subject related information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Student_Subject` (
`id`
`subject_id` ,
`student_id` 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The subject_id and student_id will be foreign keys. Id of this table will be primary key. This way you can have one to many relationship.

Comment: I have created above table..but not getting all subjects with student id